# Passar valor $_FILES via Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário do qual é enviado um arquivo em anexo por e-mail. O problema é que quando vou enviar o arquivo via upload, parece que não passa o valor do `$_FILES` via `formulário/jquery`. Veja abaixo:

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post">
     <div id="success"></div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="career-name">Nome</label>
         <input type="text" name="Nome" class="form-control" id="nome">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="career-name">E-mail</label>
          <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" id="email">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="career-name">Vaga pretendida</label>
          <input type="text" name="Vaga" class="form-control" id="vaga">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="career-resume">Currículo</label>
          <input type="file" name="Arquivo" class="form-control" id="curriculo">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.post("includes/enviar-curriculo.php", $(".contact-form").serialize(), function(response) {
          $('#success').html(response);
        $('#nome').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#vaga').val('');
        $('#mensagem').val('');
      $('#curriculo').val('');
        });
      return false;
      });
</script>
```

**ARQUIVO PHP**

```
<?php
....
$curriculo = $_FILES["Arquivo"];
echo $curriculo['name'];
....
?>
```

É possível passar valores `$_FILES` via Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim. No evento `submit` do seu formulário, através do seu ajax você vai enviar o `data` como `new FormData(this)`. Segue exemplo.

```
<form name="form1" id="send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="nome" />
</form>
```

e no seu ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: new FormData(this),

  success: function(){  }
});
```

No seu PHP você vai captar o valor da seguinte forma

```
<?php 
  echo $_FILES["nome"]["name"];
?>
```

Comment: Olá Mauro. O problema está no campo de upload $_FILES. Os outros campos estão indo corretamente.

Comment: Editado. Verifique agora.